# Light a Mesh From All Sides

Tags: babylonjs

I am trying to create a representation of an LED (i.e. light bulb) which emits light of varying colors in all directions. Additionally, it must do so independently of other LEDs on the canvas such that each diode can have its own color.

When I first found Babylon, I thought it was logical to simple use a `PointLight` -- an LED is just a point which emits light -- however it seems to me that a mesh must reflect the light in order for it to be visible. Working under that assumption, I have tried to light a sphere with a `DirectionalLight` and a `HemisphericLight`, but neither lights one a single sphere *while* lighting every surface of the sphere.

**Is there an easy solution here or do I need to put multiple lights of some kind on each "bulb"?**

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use the `emissiveColor` material property to give a "bulb" object the illusion of reflecting a light which does not exist.  [This demo](https://playground.babylonjs.com/#Z091YU%231) shows the effect.

Thank you to @Temechon and @Wingnut for providing the tip on [this forum post!](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/30334-light-a-mesh-from-all-sides/)